# Configuring a service unit to launch a bash script. Why is this failing?

Tags: bash, services, systemd-unit

I am asking systemd to supervise and control a process but for some reason, it is failing.
Check the output at the end of the question

I have a bash script in `/usr/sbin/ros_diagnostics.sh` that launches several processes. When I execute the script in a terminal, it works great.

```
userk@histamine:~$ /usr/sbin/./ros_diagnostics.sh
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/userk/.ros/log/2023-03-09-11-55-58-140994-histamine-4737
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [aggregator_node-1]: process started with pid [4739]
[INFO] [diagnostics_updater-2]: process started with pid [4741]
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.452807708] [AnalyzerGroup]: Retrieved 7 parameter(s) for analyzer group with prefix ''.
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.452943046] [AnalyzerGroup]: Group '/Testrig', creating diagnostic_aggregator/AnalyzerGroup 'Create3' (breadcrumb: create3) ...
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.454561926] [AnalyzerGroup]: Retrieved 5 parameter(s) for analyzer group with prefix 'create3'.
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.454630094] [AnalyzerGroup]: Group '/Testrig/Create3', creating diagnostic_aggregator/GenericAnalyzer 'Propulsion' (breadcrumb: analyzers.propulsion) ...
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.454962645] [GenericAnalyzerBase]: Initialized analyzer 'Propulsion' with path '/Testrig/Create3/Propulsion' and breadcrumb 'create3.analyzers.propulsion'.
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.455007938] [AnalyzerGroup]: Adding analyzer 'Propulsion' to group '/Testrig/Create3'.
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.455031856] [AnalyzerGroup]: Initialized analyzer group '/Testrig/Create3' with path '/Testrig/Create3' and breadcrumb 'create3'.
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.455047106] [AnalyzerGroup]: Adding analyzer '/Testrig/Create3' to group '/Testrig'.
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.455061398] [AnalyzerGroup]: Initialized analyzer group 'Testrig' with path '/Testrig' and breadcrumb ''.
[aggregator_node-1] [INFO] [1678362958.455081024] [GenericAnalyzerBase]: Initialized analyzer 'Other' with path '/Testrig/Other' and breadcrumb ''.
```

Here is the output of `pstree` when the script is launched manually from a `tmux` session.

```
├─tmux: server─┬─bash───pstree
│              ├─bash
│              └─bash───ros_diagnostics───ros2─┬─aggregator_node───10*[{aggregator_node}]
│                                              ├─diagnostics_upd───9*[{diagnostics_upd}]
│                                              └─2*[{ros2}]
```

I am trying to configure a service unit to execute this script at startup. This is the service unit file

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target 

[Service]
Type=simple
User=userk
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ros_diagnostics.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

enable the service, reload the daemon, start it and ... it dies. This is the output of `sudo systemctl status ros_diagnostics.service`

```
userk@histamine:~$ sudo systemctl status ros_diagnostics.service
● ros_diagnostics.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ros_diagnostics.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2023-03-09 11:37:38 UTC; 9min ago
    Process: 4519 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ros_diagnostics.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 4519 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 09 11:37:36 histamine systemd[1]: Started ros_diagnostics.service.
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/userk/.ros/log/2023-03-09-11-37-38-219143-histamine-4577
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [INFO] [aggregator_node-1]: process started with pid [4579]
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [INFO] [diagnostics_updater-2]: process started with pid [4581]
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [aggregator_node-1] /opt/ros/foxy/lib/diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node: >
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [ERROR] [aggregator_node-1]: process has died [pid 4579, exit code 127, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node --ros-args --params-file /home/userk/development/ros2/galactic_ws/install/robot_diagnostics/share/robot_diagnostics/config/diagnostics.yaml -r /diagnostics:=diagnostics -r /diagnostics_agg:=diagnostics_agg -r /diagnostics_toplevel_state:=diagnostics_toplevel_state'].
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [INFO] [diagnostics_updater-2]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[diagnostic>
Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine ros_diagnostics.sh[4577]: [ERROR] [diagnostics_updater-2]: process has died [pid 4581, exit code -2, cmd '/home/userk/development/ros2/galactic_ws/install/robot_diagnostics/lib/robot_diagnostics/diagnostics_updater --ros-args -r /diagnostics:=diagnostics -r /diagnostics_agg:=diagnostics_agg -r /diagnostics_toplevel_state:=diagnostics_toplevel_state'].

Mar 09 11:37:38 histamine systemd[1]: ros_diagnostics.service: Succeeded.
```

**NB**
The outputs of the bash script are different.  Not sure here if there is an old (cached?) version of the script that is being used instead of the new one.
A previous version of the script was defective and failed to start. I created the unit file at that time and then modified the script and fixed its problem.

Is the unit configuration incorrect, any advice?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "old (cached?) version of the script". Probably something like environment variables, current working directory, terminal is different when you start your script from `systemd` or from your login shell, and this might have an influence on your programs. Do the programs `/opt/ros/foxy/lib/diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node` and `/home/userk/development/ros2/galactic_ws/install/robot_diagnostics/lib/robot_diagnostics/diagnostics_updater` have log files where you can see details about the unexpected termination? What do the exit codes 127 and -2 mean?

Comment: As @Bodo mentioned, it might be environment issue. Can you please try to remove the `User` line and change the exec to `ExecStart=/usr/bin/su - userk -c /usr/sbin/ros_diagnostics.sh` and try to restart the service?

Comment: Thanks @Bodo for your input. Yes they have associated log files and they fail with this exit code 127. It is a generic error code that says that some dependency could not be located. Still not sure about the exit code -2 unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @aviro for your input. I tried your suggestion and the program failed . I had to change the path of the `su` command, mine was in `/bin/su`

Comment: I triple-checked the environment variables used and found out that I was using the wrong ones. So the problem was in the script. All good!

Comment: Not sure how to handle this Stack Exchange question. The most exhaustive answer will be accepted

Comment: You can answer your own question with the steps you did to debug it, how you found the wrong environment variable and how you fixed it, so if people encounter similar problems in the future they can follow your footsteps. You should also accept your own answer.

Comment: Ok I ll upvote your comments then